# Ifs and Arraylists

Tags: java

is there a way to do an if statement where one number is compared to an entire arraylist?
I want to ask the user to input a number, then scan the array list for that same number and then print out the number from the array list.

Comment: try list.contains(element);

Comment: even if this is your homework, you at least got to show what steps you have take so far...please show your work/code and don't just post a question. Thanks

Comment: Your question is not dumb, but you could have read the JavaDoc to find  the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `contains()`.

```
Integer someInt = Integer.valueOf(10);
if(list.contains(someInt)) {
    // other code
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to get the location of the list too?

Comment: of the positions that equal someInt*

Comment: At that point, you're iterating over the entire list using a standard for-loop, and if the element you want is found, then you retrieve the element and the index of iteration.  Honestly though, trying to get the location of the element isn't a helpful operation with regards to `List`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set` instead of a `List` here. Since, you're adding numbers you probably won't have duplicates in your list. `Set#contains()` would perform much better (near constant time) if your list is huge.